# Session data not being stored during testing in Django

Tags: python, django

I am currently writing tests for our project, and I ran into an issue. We have this section of a view, which will redirect the user back to the page where they came from including an error message (that's being stored in the session):

```
if request.GET.get('error_code'):
    """
    Something went wrong or the call was cancelled
    """
    errorCode = request.GET.get('error_code')
    if errorCode == 4201:
        request.session['errormessage'] = _('Action cancelled by the user')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/socialMedia/manageAccessToken')
```

Once the HttpResponseRedirect kicks in, the first thing that the new view does is scan the session, to see if any error messages are stored in the session. If there are, we place them in a dictionary and then delete it from the session:

```
def manageAccessToken(request):
"""
View that handles all things related to the access tokens for Facebook,
Twitter and Linkedin.
"""
contextDict = {}
try:
    contextDict['errormessage'] = request.session['errormessage']
    contextDict['successmessage'] = request.session['successmessage']
    del request.session['errormessage']
    del request.session['successmessage']
except KeyError:
    pass
```

We should now have the error message in a dictionary, but after printing the dictionary the error message is not there. I also printed the session just before the HttpResponseRedirect, but the session is an empty dictionary there as well.

This is the test:

```
class oauthCallbacks(TestCase):
"""
Class to test the different oauth callbacks
"""

def setUp(self):
    self.user = User.objects.create(
        email='test@django.com'
    )
    self.c = Client()

def test_oauthCallbackFacebookErrorCode(self):
    """
    Tests the Facebook oauth callback view
    This call contains an error code, so we will be redirected to the
    manage accesstoken page. We check if we get the error message
    """
    self.c.force_login(self.user)
    response = self.c.get('/socialMedia/oauthCallbackFacebook/',
                          data={'error_code': 4201},
                          follow=True,
                          )

    self.assertEqual('Action cancelled by the user', response.context['errormessage'])
```

It looks like the session can not be accessed or written to directly from the views during testing. I can, however, access a value in the session by manually setting it in the test by using the following bit of code:

```
    session = self.c.session
    session['errormessage'] = 'This is an error message'
    session.save()
```

This is however not what I want, because I need the session to be set by the view as there are many different error messages in the entire view. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a closer look I found the issue, it is in the view itself:

```
errorCode = request.GET.get('error_code')
if errorCode == 4201:
    request.session['errormessage'] = _('Action cancelled by the user')
```

The errorCode variable is a string, and I was comparing it to an integer. I fixed it by changing the second line to:

```
if int(errorCode) == 4201:
```